# How can we measure thickness of a wet film without destroying it's surface?

Tags: material-science, measurements, spectroscopy, optical-materials

I have an opaque(wet) material thin film on a glass plate. How can I measure the thickness of the film without destroying the surface?

I am thinking that I might be able to use a spectroscopic technique. Other than that is there any direct method?

Answer (score 1):

the direct method is called *ellipsometry* and is commonly used in the integrated circuit industry to measure the thickness of dielectric (transparent) thin films.

Comment: Thanks. I will read more about it.